# /developer directory is missing in Lion Xcode 4.3

Tags: ios, xcode, osx-lion

I removed an older version of Xcode following the instructions in [How to fully remove Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255959/how-to-fully-remove-xcode-4) and then installed version 4.3 from AppStore. But now /developer directory is missing.

I can find the same directory structure in /applications/xcode.app/contents/Developer/. Is /developer just a link to that directory and how can I create it again?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to the [XCode 4.3 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_3.html), the /developer directory is no longer needed.

> **/Developer No Longer Exists**
>
> The simplification afforded by repackaging
>   Xcode 4.3 as a single app bundle eliminates the need for the
>   /Developer directory containing prior versions of Xcode. As a result,
>   the Install Xcode application and the uninstall-devtools command line
>   script are also no longer needed.

Comment: So how do you uninstall Xcode ? My Mac App Store is stuck on "Installing..." when I tried to update my Xcode to the 5.1 SDK. Launching Xcode is just crashing it. Should I just drag it into trash like other apps?

Comment: Yes, with XCode 4.3 you can just drag it to the Trash like other apps.

Comment: Interesting. My xcode update was stuck at 1 minute remaining for half an hour and I wasn't able to drag the existing xcode.app into trash. I did an rm -rf on `/Applications/Xcode.app` and reinstalled Xcode which worked, so thanks!

Comment: I just installed Lion and now I'm downloading Xcode from the app store. It seems to be installing to the /Developer/Applications folder! (on launch pad, it appears as 'downloading' inside an iOS-like folder together with the existing Interments, DashCode and QuartzComposer) . I did this before on another Mac but then it installed a new copy in /Applications. What's going on?

Comment: I actually had the whole bunch of things in /Developer folder, like Qt stuff, CUDA and GPU computing kits. The Xcode 4.3 installer just blindly moved all that to recycle bin, so I had to restore the folder.

Answer (score 5):

The /Developer directory is no longer used by Xcode as **jonkroll** noted.

If you are looking for command line tools, you can install them using the Components tab of the Downloads preferences panel.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you're right, now /Developer directory is embedded into XCode.app. So you have to make an alias to this new directory or change your path to this new folder.

Comment: This comment helped a lot. The full path is /Applications/XCode.app/Contents/Developer  (some older books refer to the /Developer directory for certain things, like looking for supported platforms)

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to get to it is to right click on an existing framework that you have imported in your project; then choose "open in finder".  Then you can hit option + the up arrow key on your key board to traverse up to the developer folder (e.g if you want to peruse the contents of your simulator documents folder etc...) & make a short cut to it for direct navigation..

Answer (score 0):

Switching directories worked for me:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /
```