# Qt4 won't compile with CMake

Tags: c++, ubuntu, qt4, cmake

I'm now under Linux with KDevelop for C++ and I want to compile a Qt4 application, but when I do, it gives me the following error :

I compile with:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug /home/myname/projects/First Qt projet/
```

Those are the errors:

```
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:97 (MESSAGE):
  Could NOT find Qt4 (missing: QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE QT_MOC_EXECUTABLE
  QT_RCC_EXECUTABLE QT_UIC_EXECUTABLE QT_INCLUDE_DIR QT_LIBRARY_DIR
  QT_QTCORE_LIBRARY)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:288 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:1200 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package)
```

What should I do ?

Comment: It can't find your qt4 install.  It's usually under /usr/lib/qt4.*

Comment: How do I install it ?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Linux ubuntu 12.10 64 bits

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install libqt4-core libqt4-dev libqt4-gui qt4-dev-tools
```

This should install qt4 for you in: /usr/lib64/qt... from there `cmake` should be able to pick up the location of qt for you.

You can also use that Ubuntu package manager thingy if command line isn't your style.

Comment: (Ghost of lost software updates):
Don't uuuuusssseee thhheeee paaaaccckaaage maaannnager GModCake...
Youuuuu'll ruuun deepppreeecatttedd cooodddeee...

Comment: @Freestyle076 - Are you suggesting not to use apt-get?  Also, this answer is from over 3 years ago, so it being dated isn't surprising?

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if this will help anyone, but for Fedora, i had the following issue:

> CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:1386 (message):
>     Found unsuitable Qt version "" from NOTFOUND, this code requires Qt 4.x
>   Call Stack (most recent call first):
>     bgrive/CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package)

After stepping through FindQt4.cmake i found this:

```
if (NOT QT_VERSION_MAJOR EQUAL 4)
    set(VERSION_MSG "Found unsuitable Qt version \"${QTVERSION}\" from ${QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE}")
    set(QT4_FOUND FALSE)
    if(Qt4_FIND_REQUIRED)
       message( FATAL_ERROR "${VERSION_MSG}, this code requires Qt 4.x")
    else()
      if(NOT Qt4_FIND_QUIETLY)
         message( STATUS    "${VERSION_MSG}")
      endif()
    endif()
else()
  FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS(Qt4 FOUND_VAR Qt4_FOUND
    REQUIRED_VARS ${_QT4_FOUND_REQUIRED_VARS}
    VERSION_VAR QTVERSION
    )
endif()
```

I know i have qt 4I solved this by simply doing:

```
sudo yum install qt-devel
```